# Flutter | Stop music when minimised using audioplayers

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, flutter-dependencies

In my app, I am playing music (local) in a loop, which plays continuously unless the user stops it. I am using audioplayers package.

```
Future playLoop(String filePath) async {
  player.stop();
  player = await cache.loop(filePath);
}
```

Currently, when app is minimised, the music is not getting stoped. The feature I want to implement is that when the app is minimised, it should stop playing music in the background.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Solutions :
>
> ```
> @override
>   void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
>     if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
>      //stop your audio player
>     }else{
>       print(state.toString());
>     }
>   }
>
>  @override
>   void initState() {
>     super.initState();
>     WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
>   }
> ```
>
> There are mainly 4 states for it:
>
> **resumed**: The application is visible and responding to user input.
>
> **inactive**: The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving
> user input.
>
> **paused**: The application is not currently visible to the user, not
> responding user input, and running in the background.
>
> **detached**: The application is still hosted on a flutter engine but is
> detached from any host views.

Comment: When I minimize and reopens the app, two instances of music is getting played. Why is that happening?

Comment: @Kakashi because in this example `else` happens twice (for weird reasons).This can be fixed by making the audio player null on the first call.

Answer (score 2):

The solution above is correct, but some steps are needed before to get it

1 add WidgetsBindingObserver to your class

```
class AnyClass extends StatefulWidgets {
  _AnyClassState createState() => _AnyClassState();
}

class _AnyClassState extends State<AnyClass> with 
WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
  }
}
```

2 Now it will work, we can added the methods inside class

```
class _AnyClassState extends State<AnyClass> with 
WidgetsBindingObserver {

  // ADD THIS AppLifecycleState VARIABLE 
  late AppLifecycleState appLifecycle;

  // ADD THIS FUNCTION WITH A AppLifecycleState PARAMETER
  didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    appLifecycle = state;
    setStae(() {});
    
    if(state == AppLifecycle.paused) {
      // IF YOUT APP IS IN BACKGROUND...
      // YOU CAN ADDED THE ACTION HERE
      print('My app is in background');
    }
  }
  
  // CREATE INITSTATE AND DISPOSE METHODS
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
  }
}
```

NOW IT WILL WORK FINE!